# connect form.io with SQL Server

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, formio

How can i connect SQL Server data with form.io? I have created basic form in form.io application and embedd it into the applicaton. I want to store submitted data in sql server data base. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

When you check out [this user guide page](https://help.form.io/userguide/actions/#settings-project), you will find help on the so called "SQL Connector", which can be enabled when "...your project is on the Team Pro plan or above.". Apparently this is not straight forward anyway, as it looks like you need to run the [formio-sql](https://github.com/formio/formio-sql) Service as a kind of middleware between the forms and your SQL Server, which runs on node.js. This is not the optimal setup you could probably imagine when doing ASP.NET MVC.

Disclaimer: I haven't done that myself

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Form.io team uses node package called **resquel** to do that.
Library site states following:

> This is a lightweight Express.js middleware library that is able to
>   convert SQL databases into a REST API. This library also works
>   seamlessly with the Form.io platform where you can build Angular.js
>   and React.js applications on top of your SQL database. Please go to
>   https://form.io to learn more.
>
> This library currently supports Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, and
>   PostgreSQL.

Following instructions it seems that individual tables and fields could be hooked on DB manually.

form.io platform service can obviously map your resources with tables automatically.